# How can I get my query to display all the records from 1 to max record

Tags: sql, oracle

is there a way I can get the max value for `profile_id` instead of writing out the last record 36006 in the where clause.

```
SELECT profile_id, pe_in_flag, pe_out_flag, ce_in_flag,  ce_out_flag, profile_ind 
from COS_PROFILE
WHERE profile_id >= 1 AND profile_id <= 36006;
```

I tried this query but did not work

```
SELECT profile_id, pe_in_flag, pe_out_flag, ce_in_flag,  ce_out_flag, profile_ind 
from COS_PROFILE
WHERE profile_id <= max(profile_id);
```

Comment: Why do you have a filter at all if you want all records? Can't you just remove the `where` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you have structured the query in your example, there is no reason to check for the max. It will automatically be the implied limit to the set returned on the table in which the max is on a surrogate key within itself. If you were instead wanting to join to a different table and use the max value of "that" table to limit the set returned from "this" table, then you could test "that" max to solve the problem.

As is, -assuming the index for your profile_id begins at 1- the easiest way to solve this looks to be to completely remove the filter.

`SELECT profile_id, pe_in_flag, pe_out_flag, ce_in_flag,  ce_out_flag, profile_ind 
from COS_PROFILE`

If you want to introduce explicit limits here

`SELECT profile_id, pe_in_flag, pe_out_flag, ce_in_flag,  ce_out_flag, profile_ind 
from COS_PROFILE
where profile_id >=1 AND profile_id <= (select max(profile_id) from COS_PROFILE)`

but the filter is pointless.